# Scraping a web page using Node js in Javascript extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, request, cheerio

I'm creating a javascript extension for Firefox in which I want to use a scraper page, find a sub-page and pass that URL to a function in the extension. The scraper is built using Cheerio and I've created and tested the scraper using Node.js on my local machine, but I'm having trouble implementing it in the extension. I know most likely, running an extension inside a browser, doesn't let you create a 'request' connection.

When I call the scrape function it gives no error, instead, it gives no return at all (no console logs either, so it's not firing). Does anyone know how I can call this function from an extension on any machine? Is there a way to include Node js in the extension or something like that? The code is below!

```
function scrape(item) {
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("connected");
            // create cheerio
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            $('.inner-article a').each(function (i, elem) {
                if ($(this).children().length == 1) {
                    availableItems.push($(this).attr('href'));
                }
            });

            availableItems.forEach(function (i) {
                request(url + i, function (error, response, html) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                        var title = $('#details').find('h1').text();
                        title = title.toLowerCase();
                        title = title.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                        var n = title.includes(item);
                        if (n) {
                            console.log('found');
                            itemurl = url + i + '';
                            return itemurl;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see `itemurl` initialized or declared. There is also no such thing as `item` in your code which is used here -> `title.includes(item)`.

Comment: If in fact you have `item` and `itemurl`, what does the `href` value looks like? Does it contain the full url or just part of it? Becuase if it has the full url, you just need to use `i` instead of `url+i`. I maybe wrong.

Comment: It should indeed be var itemulr, it initializes there. Item is given as a function parameter! The href is a /item value, so appended to url actually works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Requests are done a bit differently in google chrome extensions.

First off, you have to include the domain you are scraping from in the `manifest.json`.

```
"name": "Extension Name",
"permissions": [
  "http://www.example.com/"
]
```

You also have to do a XHR request, using `XMLHttpRequest` inorder to get the data you need and wait for the proper statechange you need to scrape the data. You can read more about that here:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr